# Have express serve static assets from another http server (webpack dev server)

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Backend beginner here.  I have a node/express rest api from which, in development, I would like to serve an angular2.x/4.x web app from the webpack-dev-server running on port 3000.

I have the following code which works well enough to fetch index.html and javascript bundles from the dev server and return them to the client, but images do not seem to work once they arrive at the browser:

```
app.get('*', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  isProd ? useBuild(res) : useDevServer(req, res);
});

function useDevServer (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void {
  const options: any = {
    path: req.path,
    port: 3000
  };

  http.get(options, (targetRes: http.IncomingMessage) => {
    let rawData: string = '';

    targetRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      rawData += chunk;
    });
    targetRes.on('end', () => {
      res.send(rawData);
    });
  }).on('error', e => {
    console.warn(`\nGot error: ${e.message}\n`);
  });
}
```

This code proxies the image requests from index.html to the webpack dev server, and responses return 200.  However, something is wrong because I can't see the response bodies in the browser network tab and the response headers include `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`.  Manually setting that header to `image/jpeg` does not seem to help.

I hope the issue is that I'm seeing something which is quite obvious to people who work with backend services regularly, but if not and this looks reasonable it would be good to know that too.  Thanks!

Comment: posting your webpack config would help here as well; you may be doing something with the images other than just serving them.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote you don't really have to run the webpack-dev-server in development.  You could just as easily run webpack in watch mode, such that it rebuilds your client files every time there's a change.  This simplifies your Express code and makes your environment closer to production, which means you're less likely to run into bugs in production that aren't in development.

Comment: @Paul Oh that's great!  I had forgotten about running webpack in watch mode, completely agree that's a much better approach.  Thanks!